# Вывод постов подкатегорий на одной странице в виде архива wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Сейчас для каждой категории приходиться делать  отдельную страницу-шаблон (т.е  в wordpress'e лежат файлы `cat5-2014year.php`, `cat5-2013year.php`, `cat5-2015year.php`, для каждого шаблона есть ссылка). Получается что-то типа архива  по категориям.

Нужно  сделать, чтобы  все выводилось через  одну страницу-шаблон,  а с помощью ссылок можно было переходить  на страницы с выборкой за 2014, 2015, 2013 год. 
Как я понимаю надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку  например "2015 год" менялся этот параметр `'year' => 2015`.

```
<a href="http://mysite/?page_id=125">2015 год</a>
<a href="http://mysite/?page_id=126">2014 год</a>
<a href="http://mysite/?page_id=127">2013 год</a>
    <?php
        //for each category, show all posts
        $cat_args=array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'order' => 'ASC'
           );
        $categories=get_categories($cat_args);
          foreach($categories as $category) {
            $args=array(
              'showposts' => -1,
              'category_name' => 'cat5',
              'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
              'year' => 2015,
              'caller_get_posts'=>1
            );
            $posts=get_posts($args);
              if ($posts) {
                echo '<p>Категория: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Посмотреть все посты в категории %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
                foreach($posts as $post) {
                  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                  <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Прямая ссылка: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                  <?php
                }
              }
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, год можно отправить `get` запросом. В таком случае адрес страницы будет в виде `page.php?year=2015`, а сам код в виде

```
<a href="http://mysite/?page_id=125">2015 год</a>
<a href="http://mysite/?page_id=126">2014 год</a>
<a href="http://mysite/?page_id=127">2013 год</a>
    <?php

        $year = !empty($_GET['year']) ? abs(intval($_GET['year'])) : '2015'; // По умолчанию год 2015-ый

        //for each category, show all posts
        $cat_args=array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'order' => 'ASC'
           );
        $categories=get_categories($cat_args);
          foreach($categories as $category) {
            $args=array(
              'showposts' => -1,
              'category_name' => 'cat5',
              'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
              'year' => $year,
              'caller_get_posts'=>1
            );
            $posts=get_posts($args);
              if ($posts) {
                echo '<p>Категория: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Посмотреть все посты в категории %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
            foreach($posts as $post) {
              setup_postdata($post); ?>
              <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Прямая ссылка: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php the_content(); ?></p>
              <?php
            }
          }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно.  Единственная заминка , если  использовать   категорию (например: http://mysite/?cat=5&year=2015)  и если подставить  в ссылке  буквенное значение (пример: http://mysite/?cat=5&year=sffd),  то он выводит все посты категории. Если подставлять цифры , то все корректно работает.

Comment: Можно усовершенствовать фильтр. `$year = (!empty($_GET['year']) && is_numeric($_GET['year'])) ? abs(intval($_GET['year'])) : '2015';` В идеале, неплохо бы еще и запрос сделать в базу на существование года.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню: ссылки при этом должны принять вид:

```
<a href="http://mysite/?page_id=125&year=2013">2013 год</a>
<a href="http://mysite/?page_id=125&year=2014">2014 год</a>
<a href="http://mysite/?page_id=125&year=2015">2015 год</a>
```

т.е. все ссылки ссылаются на один шаблон, но передают в него еще один параметр.

Остальное верно написал предыдущий автор:

```
    <?php

        $year = !empty($_GET['year']) ? abs(intval($_GET['year'])) : '2015'; // По умолчанию год 2015-ый

        //for each category, show all posts
        $cat_args=array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'order' => 'ASC'
           );
        $categories=get_categories($cat_args);
          foreach($categories as $category) {
            $args=array(
              'showposts' => -1,
              'category_name' => 'cat5',
              'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
              'year' => $year,
              'caller_get_posts'=>1
            );
            $posts=get_posts($args);
              if ($posts) {
                echo '<p>Категория: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Посмотреть все посты в категории %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
            foreach($posts as $post) {
              setup_postdata($post); ?>
              <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Прямая ссылка: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php the_content(); ?></p>
              <?php
            }
          }
        }
    ?>
```